# Popup Form out of a material-ui menu does not recognize Tabindex

Tags: material-ui

I have a material-ui menu that is declared as follows but when the Dialog with Form opens then the fields are not accessible by pressing the Tab key... If I open the Dialog outside of the Menu then everything is alright. Any ideas?

```
 <Menu
        id="device-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
<MenuItem className="lb_menu_item"  onClick={handleChPasswd}>
<div>
      <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} tabindex="0">
        <span>{props.label}</span>
      </Button>
      <Dialog className={"lb_alert_dialog " + props.className} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <div style={{width: "100%", textAlign: "center"}}>{props.title}</div>
        <DialogContent>
            <FormControl className="lock_dialog" style={{padding:0}} focused={true}>
         <TextField label="user" value="" textAlign="left"/>
         <TextField label="password" value="" />
            </FormControl>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button>Login</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In FF Inspector I expected to see a difference between the two states (Dialog inside and outside of Menu) but I did not find any difference